How can I install Just dance save data From one wii to another?
I was playing games on my Wii mini, and this year I got a new Wii (the normal one with all the features). I am now trying to transfer all my save data from my Wii mini to my new one, but there's a problem with:

Just Dance 2
Just Dance 3
Just Dance 2014
Just Dance 2015

They all just give me the error: (Unable to copy datas). Since the Wii mini only has a USB slot (USB hubs don't work) I transfer the data to a USB and put it in my new one, which works with every other game I own... And in the data management setting, I can't move it even if I turn on "Remove NoCopy Save File Protection" in priloader. I've even tried putting the save file on my SD card and importing it in that way, but it won't work!
